# Is it possible to know the coordinates of a line at a specific point in time in python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

This is the game that I have made I want the circle that has been generated to move across the line without actually touching it, the circle moves to the right and downwards when no keypresses are made and is supposed to jump when the spacebar is pressed, when it collides with the line (logic I made for hitreg) it will restart with a brand new line and the circle at the starting position. When it goes from one end to the other it'll restart with a new line that has more divisions so that the game is difficult as you progress through the levels. The only issue I am having right now is that I am not able to start up the game correctly without it exiting the code immediately and I think the reason might be that the coordinates I have calculated are not accurate enough and sometimes the circle crosses the line and still doesn't register a collision.

**Code for the game**

```
from tkinter import *
from random import randint as rand
import keyboard, math

window = Tk()
window.geometry("1440x720")
canvas = Canvas(window, width=1440, height=720, 
bg="white")

l1, l2, l3 = [], [], []
x = 1
b = canvas.create_oval(0, 300, 10, 300 + 60)
c = b

def genLine():
    global x
    f = 0
    z = 360
    y = 1440 / x
    while x != 0:
        ran = rand(300, 420)
        u = canvas.create_line(f, z, y, ran)
        r = canvas.coords(u)
        l1.append(r)
        f = y
        x -= 1
        y += y
        z = ran

def hitReg():
    global l2, l3
    for i in l1:
        grad = ((i[3] - i[1]) / (i[2] - i[0]))
        l2.append(grad)
    for i in l2:
        for f in l1:
            x = 0
            length = f[2] - f[0]
            while x != length:
                point = x * i + f[1]
                l3.append(math.ceil( point))
                x += 0.25

def move_b():
    global l3, x
    canvas.move(c, 1, 1)
    y = canvas.coords(c)
    if keyboard.is_pressed('space'):
        canvas.move(b, 1, -5)
    elif y[1] in l3 or y[3] in l3:
        exit()
    elif y[2] >= 1440:
        x += 1
        genLine()
        hitReg()
        move_b()
    else:
        pass
    window.after(10, move_b)

genLine()
hitReg()
move_b()

canvas.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: first you could use `print()` to see values in variables (and which part of code is executed). It is called `"print debuging"`. It may help to see if it works as you expect.

Comment: tkinter can use `bind(key, function)`, to detect when space is pressed - so you don't need extra module `keyboard`. On Linux `keyboard` needs to run code as `admin` and it makes big problem.

Comment: you could format code - put all function directly after `import`, use names of variable which means something (i.e. `oval` instead of `b`), etc. to make code more readable. See more [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: as for me problem can make `elif y[1] in l3 or y[3] in l3:` because it has `y` values for all `x` and `y[1]` or `y[3]` can match with `y` which is on other end of line. You would have to to check `y[1]`  `y[3]` only with values in `l3` which have the same `x` (or very similar `x`). Maybe it would be simpler to use `canvas.find_overlapping()` or `canvas.find_closest()` but it would need to create object on canvas instead of list of `y` values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main problem is

```
elif y[1] in l3 or y[3] in l3:
```

because `l3` has all `y` values which are on line and it compares `y[1]` and `y[3]` with all `y` values but it should compare only with the nearest - with point which has the same `x` as center of `oval`.

I was thinking to use `canvas.find_overlapping()` or `canvas.find_closest()` but it would need to create small `rectange` or small `oval` for every hit point on line.

Finally I created hit points every `1px` instead of `0.25px` so I could put them on list and easily get

```
point_y = points[ int(oval_center_x) ]
```

and later check `oval_y1 < point_y < oval_y2`.

I also used `window.bind("<space>", function)` to move `oval` so I don't need extra module `keyboard`. Besides, I use Linux and `keyboard` on Linux needs `admin` privilege.

I also changed names of variables and functions to make them more readable.

As for `exit()` I created function `reset()` which sets `level`, removes all lines `canvas.delete(*lines)`, moves `oval` to beginning  `canvas.moveto(oval, 0, 330)`, and generates new line (using value `level`) and generates `hit points`. Using `reset(level+1)` I can generate next level, and using `reset(1)` I can go back to first level.

```
import tkinter as tk        # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
from random import randint  # PEP8: every module in separted line

# --- functions ---  # PEP8: all functions directly after imports
                     # PEP8: `lower_case_names` for functions and variables

def generate_lines(level):
    
    regions = []
    lines = []
        
    x1 = 0
    y1 = 360
    
    step = 1440 / level 
    
    x2 = step
    
    for i in range(level):
        y2 = randint(300, 420)  # 360-60, 360+60
        
        region = (x1, y1, x2, y2)
        regions.append(region)

        line = canvas.create_line(x1, y1, x2, y2)
        lines.append(line)
        
        x1 = x2
        y1 = y2

        x2 += step

    return lines, regions
    
def generate_hit_points(regions):
    
    points = []

    for x1,y1,x2,y2 in regions:
        
        steps = int(x2 - x1)
        dy = (y2 - y1) / steps
        
        y = y1
        
        for _ in range(steps):   # cant use `range(y1, y2, dy)` because `dy` is `float`, not `int`

            points.append(y)  # I don't need `x`
            
            y += dy

    return points
    
def move_oval():

    canvas.move(oval, 1, 1)
    
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = canvas.coords(oval)
    
    oval_center_x = int(x1+10)
    point_y = points[oval_center_x]
    #print(y1, '<', int(point_y), '<', y2, '?')

    #if y1 >= point_y or point_y >= y2:  # less readable
    if not (y1 < point_y < y2):          # more readable
        print('end')
        reset(1)
        
    elif x2 >= 1440:
        print('next level')
        reset(level+1)
        
    window.after(25, move_oval)

def on_press_space(event):
    canvas.move(oval, 0, -15)

def reset(new_level):
    # all globals moved to one function
    global lines
    global points
    global level
    
    level = new_level
    
    canvas.delete(*lines)        # remove all lines
    canvas.moveto(oval, 0, 330)  # move oval to the beginning
    
    lines, regions = generate_lines(level)
    points = generate_hit_points(regions)  

# --- main ---

lines  = []  # PEP8: every variable in separted line
points = []  # PEP8: every variable in separted line

level = 1

window = tk.Tk()

window.geometry("1440x720")

canvas = tk.Canvas(window, width=1440, height=720, bg="white")
canvas.pack()

oval = canvas.create_oval(0, 360-30, 10, 360+30)

window.bind('<space>', on_press_space)
window.bind('q', lambda event:window.destroy())

reset(1)

# start moving
move_oval()

window.mainloop()
```

---

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: thank you so much for this solution, and ur documentation of the code was great